# MS Access - Enter Parameter Value on INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database, which contains information that I can't share images of due to compliance reasons.
I have a table I need to copy data from, so I was using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO completedtrainingstestfinal (MALicenseNum)
SELECT MALicenseNum
FROM CompletedTrainings
WHERE (CompletedTrainings.MALicenseNum IS NOT NULL)
AND (CompletedTrainings.Employee = completedtrainingstestfinal.Employee);
```

It keeps popping up the Enter Parameter Value, centered on the new table (named `completedtrainingstestfinal`) at the `Employee` column.

Background: The original table is a mess, and this is to be the replacement table, I've had to pivot the table in order to clean it up, and am now trying to remove an ungodly amount of nulls. The goal is to clean up the query process for the end users of this who need to put in training and certification/recertification through the forms.

When you look in the old table, it has been designed to reference another table and display the actual names, but as seen in the image below it is storing the data as the integer number Employee.
The new table Employee column was a direct copy but only displays the integer, my instincts tell me that the problem is here, but I have been unable to find a solution. Anyone have any suggestions to throw me in the right direction?

Edited to add: It might be an issue where the tables have different numbers of rows?

This is the design view of the two relevant tables :

Table 1

[image: Design View for Table 1]

Table 2

[image: Design View for Table 2]

Comment: **(CompletedTrainings.Employee = completedtrainingstestfinal.Employee)** is nonsense for an INSERT action. It would be appropriate as JOIN for an UPDATE action. I don't see a MALicenseNum field in completedtrainingstestfinal. Suggest you change table name to use title case `CompletedTrainingsTestFinal`. Also advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Well that explains it. This is (as is clearly obvious) above my level, but am literally the only one who knows any SQL at all, and they've given me the job. I need to pull just the areas where it isn't null, and ensure the data is on the right record. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'data is on the right record' - you are inserting new records so there shouldn't be a record to match. If you really want to UPDATE records, that is different issue. Should provide sample data and desired result as text tables not images. Use dummy values (Micky Mouse, Donald Duck, etc)

Comment: Yup I totally botched that, and realized it immediately after getting it to work... I am a SQL noob. Now I get to rebuild the table again, but you've pointed me in the right direction sir, thank you much.